# Winforms controls - why doesn't Text go grey when Enabled = false?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, button

I'm getting some inconsistent behavior when I disable certain Button controls in my VS2008 Winforms project.

When I set `Enabled = false`, the buttons are disabled, but the Text of some (though not all) of the buttons stays black.

I want all buttons to show grey text when disabled - this makes it much easier for the user to see that a button is disabled.

Seems more likely to happen if button is placed in a GroupBox, but I'm not sure this is always the case.

I'm guessing that some combination of properties of the Button, and/or those of the Form or GroupBox containing it are causing this, but I can't see any pattern that makes sense.

**Edit:** We have our own look and feel, and are setting the BackColor of the containing Form to a different color.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you send some sample project, where is this issue? I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: I could try.  How would I send it to you?

Comment: The obvious fix is to use the default system themes. They always paint correctly, they're customisable by the user, and they are comfortable/familiar to the user. There is never any excuse for changing the colors manually.

Comment: @Cody - provide some more info as an answer, and I'll vote you up.  Though I see from your profile that you don't really need the rep, and you have a bit of a bias towards the system themes...

Comment: @Tom: Yes, I share the bias of 99% of users. The *reason* I like system themes is because they automatically solve problems like this. Keep in mind that it's rarely a good idea to customize *some* of the colors in your app while leaving others to the system themes. If I set a high contrast theme, then it's very likely that those colors with clash with your custom colors and make your app unusable. Like you've observed here, users expect various things, like disabled buttons to take on a "grayed out" appearance, and too much customization can/does interfere with this.

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/12/6648399.aspx) for a more detailed example. In light of the costs of custom UI "skins", I haven't found a good reason to do this yet. But I'm not really interested in the votes or the rep, and I've hashed this out many places on the site before. I posted this as a comment because typically users who post this type of question are left "unsatisfied" with someone telling them not to do whatever it is they're doing in the first place. But I guarantee it's easier and far more intuitive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was because the Form's BackColor was set to a different color.

Some Googling revealed that many others have encountered this.  The proposed solutions were very complex - subclassing your own button controls and overriding OnPaint, etc.

But it turns out there is a simple fix...

When you add the buttons to the form, the button's BackColor property will be set to the same value as the Form's BackColor, although it will **not** display that way either at design or run time.

If you **set the button's BackColor property to System -> ControlLight**, it will fix the problem - the disabled buttons now look disabled.

Note that there's a strange quirk when you reset the BackColor - the UseVisualStyleBackColor property will change from True to False.  But this seems to have no effect, and can be changed back to True without affecting the appearance in any way.